# How to loop through a bunch of records with same ID value and select timestamp for one of the records that satisfy the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, apache-spark

I have a table, having numerous columns, and ORDER_LINE_ID (abbrev as OL ID), STATUS_ID, STATUS_QTY & INSERT_TS are the fields in concern.

I have a bunch of records with same OL_ID, but their STATUS_ID, QTY & INSERT_TS vary. For that particular value of OL ID,say 123, I want to loop through the bunch of data and check if any of those records have STATUS_ID 3700.8000 (This ID means 'Associate Picked'). If this satisfies, then I must select this record's corresponding STATUS_TS and insert into a field called STORE_RECEIVED_DT.

[image: Here is a sample data for a particular OL ID]

Assume that the current status is the records at the top. But sometime during the past, it has passed through the STATUS_ID 3700.8000 and then finally has attained 3950.01 status. Now, I want to select the particular INSERT_TS corresponding to 3700.8000 and store in a variable called STORE_RECEIVED_DT.

There are several thousand other OL IDs each repeating a bunch of time with diff status_ids and I want to do this process for all of them. Can someone please suggest a way to overcome this?

This is the current code for reference, but it gives wrong output:

```
SELECT ORDER_DT,
  ORDER_LINE_ID,
  ORDER_HEADER_KEY,
  ORDER_LINE_KEY,
  STATUS_ID AS LINE_STATUS, 
  --Max(CASE WHEN COLR.STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN COLR.STATUS_QTY END) UNIT,

  STATUS_QTY AS UNIT,

  STATUS_DESC AS LINE_DESCRIPTION,

  ITEM_KEY,
  PRODUCT_LINE,
  SHIP_NODE_CD,
  RECEIVING_NODE_CD,
  LINE_TOTAL_AMT,                                   --Nile bpk
  ADDITIONAL_LINE_TYPE_CD,                 --Nile bpk
  RETURN_ACTION_CD,                               --Nile bpk
  ORDER_QTY,                                             --Nile bpk
  RETURN_REASON_CD,                               --Nile bpk
  RETURN_SUB_REASON_CD,                       --Nile bpk
  RETURN_REASON_DESC,                           --Nile bpk
  RETURN_ACTION,                                     --Nile bpk
  STATUS_TS,                                        --Nile bpk

  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3700' THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) ORDER_SHIPPED_DT,
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3700.8000' THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) STORE_RECEIVED_DT,
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3700.9000' THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) CUSTOMER_PICKED_UP_DATE,
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) in ('9000','3700.01.545','3200.525','9000.300','3200.520','3700.01.540','1100.525') OR (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) >= '9000'  THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) CANCELLED_DATE,
  
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3700.9000' THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) CUSTOMER_PICKUP_TS,            --Nile bpk
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3200.050' THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) ORDER_DROP_TS,                  --Nile bpk
  
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) in ('3700.01','3700.01.01','3700.02') THEN (STATUS_TS) ELSE NULL END) RETURN_DATE,

  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) in ('1100','1100.200','1100.525','1300','1310') AND STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN (STATUS_QTY) ELSE NULL END) PENDING_OMS_QTY,

  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) in ('1500','1500.100','1500.101','3200','3200.050','3200.100','3200.200','3200.500','3200.520') AND STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN (STATUS_QTY) ELSE NULL END) PENDING_SHIPMENT_QTY,
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) in ('3700','3700.00.03','3700.01.03','3700.01.540','3700.500','3700.7777') AND STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN (STATUS_QTY) ELSE NULL END) IN_TRANSIT_QTY,

  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3700.8000' AND STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN (STATUS_QTY) ELSE NULL END) AWAITING_PICKUP_QTY,
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) ='3700.9000' AND STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN (STATUS_QTY) ELSE NULL END) CUSTOMER_PICKED_UP_QTY,
  (CASE WHEN  (TRIM(STATUS_ID)) in ('1300','1310','1500','1500.100') AND STATUS_QTY > 0 THEN (STATUS_QTY) ELSE NULL END) BO_STATUS_QTY
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ORDER_LINE_ID,ORDER_DT ORDER BY STATUS_TS DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM TEMP_SALES_ORDER_DATA 
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT *
        FROM TEMP_RET_ORDER_DATA 
        )
    ) COLR
WHERE COLR.STATUS_ID <= '9000' and COLR.STATUS_ID not in ('3700.01.545','3200.525','9000.300','3200.520','3700.01.540','1100.525') and COLR.STATUS_ID NOT IN ('3700.01.01','3700.02')
```

Comment: Please select only one DBMS and remove unrelated tags.

Comment: Instead of showing data in an image, use a table of data so we have a chance to build a table and supply a working answer. Plus - please - don't just pick database tags at random, we do need to know which dbms you use so we can answer in the correct syntax for you. (mysql != postgres != apache-spark) = confusing

Comment: Hi @PaulMaxwell thank you for your advice. I will try to work around what you have suggested. I usually add tags so that it reaches out to more people and I can get help. But will look out from next time onwards. I am working on databricks using SQL queries.

Comment: adding tags to reach more people is just the wrong way of looking at it. what you want are just those folks who know how to solve your problem. more numbers does not equal relevance. additionally using just the correct tags reduces "noise" for those looking for information on a specific tag. PLEASE do not use unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 1):

A "generic SQL" solution for this could be to use a "correleated subquery" (query 1) or a joined "derived table" (query 2)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ORDER_LINE_ID` int, `STATUS_ID` decimal(8,2), `STATUS_QTY` int, `INSERT_TS` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ORDER_LINE_ID`, `STATUS_ID`, `STATUS_QTY`, `INSERT_TS`)
VALUES
    (712536734, 3950.01, 1, '2021-04-27 23:44:27'),
    (712536734, 3700, 0, '2021-04-03 14:44:28'),
    (712536734, 3700.8, 5, '2021-04-27 04:44:29'),
    (712536734, 3700.01, 0, '2021-04-27 14:10:30')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      order_line_id
    , status_id
    , status_qty
    , insert_ts
    , (select insert_ts
       from table1 as prev
       where prev.order_line_id = t1.order_line_id
       and prev.status_id = 3700.8
       ) as store_received_dt
from table1 as t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2484753/1/0)**:

```
| order_line_id | status_id | status_qty |            insert_ts |    store_received_dt |
|---------------|-----------|------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|     712536734 |   3950.01 |          1 | 2021-04-27T23:44:27Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
|     712536734 |      3700 |          0 | 2021-04-03T14:44:28Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
|     712536734 |    3700.8 |          5 | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
|     712536734 |   3700.01 |          0 | 2021-04-27T14:10:30Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select
      t1.order_line_id
    , t1.status_id
    , t1.status_qty
    , t1.insert_ts
    , prev.store_received_dt
from table1 as t1
left join (select order_line_id, insert_ts as store_received_dt
       from table1 as prev
       where status_id = 3700.8
       ) prev on t1.order_line_id = prev.order_line_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2484753/1/0)**:

```
| order_line_id | status_id | status_qty |            insert_ts |    store_received_dt |
|---------------|-----------|------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|     712536734 |   3950.01 |          1 | 2021-04-27T23:44:27Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
|     712536734 |      3700 |          0 | 2021-04-03T14:44:28Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
|     712536734 |    3700.8 |          5 | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
|     712536734 |   3700.01 |          0 | 2021-04-27T14:10:30Z | 2021-04-27T04:44:29Z |
```

Comment: Please note the potential benefit (to you!) of providing sample data in a reusable manner

Comment: Hi @Paul can you please inform what is a correlated subquery? I haven't heard of this. And what have you done in the first block? Just merely looks like a create table stmt to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery || yes the first block is to create a table this allows you (and other readers) to see the extent of the sample data that the query is dealing with and also to allow you easily trace the displayed results back to the source data.

Comment: note also there are active hyperlinks to sqlfiddle.com as well e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2484753/2